# Running python scripts from DOS or python shell without path name

Tags: python, windows-7, dos

I was attempting to edit the registry so when I type into either the python shell or a DOS window:

```
python sample.py
```

I want it to go to the directory that I save my .py files to and run the file without me having to type:

```
python C:\PythonPractice\sample.py
```

any ideas?

Comment: Meaning, you are not interested in having the Python program do this for you?

Comment: See answer to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934675/how-to-execute-python-scripts-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

For the DOS window:

```
set VARIABLE=yourpath
python %VARIABLE%\sample.py
```

So for your example you could do this:

```
set p=C:\PythonPractice
python %p%\sample.py
```

You can setup this permanently by going to "Control Panel">>"System">>"Advanced system settings">>"Environment Variables". You probably want to add a variable to your account, unless you want it to affect all of the system profiles. A restart is probably required.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
c:
CD c:\py
c:\python271\python.exe %1
```

Save that as `py.bat` in a dir on your `PATH`. Change c:\py to the directory of your scripts.

You can call your scripts from everywhere like this:

```
C:\Windows>py hallowelt.py
Hallo!
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight improvement to Jacob's answer:

```
@echo off
pushd c:\py
c:\python271\python.exe %*
popd
```

Save this as *py.cmd* in one of the directories from your your PATH environment variable. Then you can call

```
py sample.py arg1 arg2 ...
```

This works with any number of arguments.

But, as wberry mentioned, you could change the working directory from inside your Python script as well, if you really need to (but I think that's a bad idea):

```
os.chdir(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))) #untested
```

While this isn't exactly an answer to your question, I recommend using the following pattern:
Say, I have a Python script *c:\mydir\myprog.py* that requires special environment variables (PATH, ORACLE_HOME, whatever) and maybe it needs a particular working directory.

Then I create a file *myprog.cmd* in the same directory:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set PATH=...
set ORACLE_HOME=...
pushd %~dp0
python %~dpn0.py %*
popd
endlocal
```

The pushd/popd part is for changing and restoring the working directory.

For an explanation of the %~... Syntax, type

```
help call
```

at the command prompt.

This approach gives you full control about the environment of your Python program.
Note that the python call is generic: If you need a second Python script *otherprog.py*, then just save a copy of myprog.cmd as *otherprog.cmd*.