# Using argparse in Python - and default file association

Tags: python, windows, argparse

i have a file called "test.py" that imports argparse with the simple code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Description')
parser.add_argument('-e','--event', help='event', required=True)
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
myArgument = args['event']
```

from windows if i call it with

```
python "test.py" -e hello
```

it works fine but if i try to call it directly with

```
test.py -e hello
```

it is calling python but i get an error "-e/--event is required" - i.e. it's not passing the arguments along.

my associations in windows are set up as:

```
assoc .py
.py=Python.File

ftype Python.File
Python.File = "C:\Python27,python.exe" "%1" %*
```

Can't seem to figure this out, because i have it working on another computer, so i'm guessing i have some path or environment variable not set up right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related: [Python script losing arguments when run from PATH on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10281595/95735), [How to execute Python scripts in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1934675/95735)

Answer (score 2):

I think there's an error in your file associations.
I think this:

```
Python.File = "C:\Python27,python.exe" "%1" %*
```

should be:

```
Python.File = "C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

(change `,` to `\`)

...if this was just a typo here, then [this](https://superuser.com/questions/204354/how-do-i-get-ftype-assoc-to-match-windows-explorer) question and answers may be of interest.

Basically, these associations aren't necessarily what is called when you run the program.  (ie. I basically have the same associations as you, but if I run a python program like: "test.py -e hello", the progam test.py just opens up in my editor - it doesn't actually run the python program.)

You may want to look in both:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.py, and
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.py

for associations there.

Answer (score 2):

`ftype` shows what's in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` but values in this registry branch could have been overwritten by values from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`. See what's the output of `reg query HKCU\Software\Classes\Python.File\shell\open\command /ve`. I guess your problem is caused by the lack of `%*` fragment in this registry entry.