# How to make Python warn about Tab errors on Windows

Tags: python, windows-7

For python on Linux, I use `#!/usr/bin/python -tt` for issuing errors.  How do I do this on windows 7?  I tried this:

```
 #!c:\python33\python -tt
```

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not support "hashbang" syntax. You can get some support through Vinay Sajip's [pylauncher](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pylauncher), but I don't know if that will support adding parameters.

Perhaps it's possible to add the parameter in the ftype setting. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934675/how-to-execute-python-scripts-in-windows).

If not you probably have to create a .bat file that adds the parameter and associate that bat file.

Comment: You associate the .py extension with the bat file.