# Execute python script by absolute path

Tags: python, windows

I want to execute abc python script from `xyz` python script by giving the absolute path of the `abc` in `xyz`. eg. if I do

```
import main
main.someFunction
```

it gets executed but at the same place if I do

```
"D/karan/workspace/python/main".someFunction
```

it does not work.. Please suggest me what to do. 
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute Python scripts in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934675/how-to-execute-python-scripts-in-windows)

Comment: You're doing it wrong. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-folder and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python