# Unable to make Python work in command prompt

Tags: python, path, cmd, windows-7-x64, python-3.4

Trying to start using python, but I cannot make it run from CMD by simply typing `Python`.

I have added it in the system paths thing as many tutorials have taught me, and currently I have **"Python"** patched towards :

`C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts\`

as I've seen in one of them tutorials.

Also tried simple `C:\Python34\` without any success. Using **Win7** and have Python on default installation directory being clear the **"python.exe"** is located in **"C:\Python34"**

Have I missed something?

Comment: What does set command show, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327495/list-all-environment-variables-from-command-line

Comment: @JohnBarça Amongst many private data I choose not to tell, it says a bit down "Python=C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts\". From what I understand, it should also be in the "Patch=...", but it is not.

Comment: Do you mean path? Yes, it should be in path.

Comment: Yes, so sorry my grammar is through the window.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to run python from CMD. If you have python 2 and 3 both installed on your Windows you can try `py -2` or `py -3` to run different python versions. If you got not recognized error then you should add `C:\Windows` path to your environment variables. To do that goto `Control Panel\System\Advanced System Settings` and select `Environment variables` from `Advanced` tab. Find `PATH` from system variables and add `;C:\Windows` to the end of `PATH` value. Also you can take a look at [How to run different python versions in cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786478/how-to-run-different-python-versions-in-cmd) to find other ways.