# Error for numpy and scipy after Installation of pythonxy

Tags: numpy, scipy, pythonxy

I recieved an error after the installation of pythonxy, as far as I know pythonxy including numpy and scipy, however I can't import these features on the command prompt.
How can I deal this problem ?
Here is my error message, thank you stackoverflow community.

```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>python
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'scipy'
```

Answer (score 0):

Python(x,y) installs Python 2.7. It seems that you have started Python 3. The discussion in [How to run different python versions in cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786478/how-to-run-different-python-versions-in-cmd) might help.