# launching a python 2.7 script from a Python 3 script

Tags: python-2.7, compatibility

I am trying to launch a python 2.7 script called `pp.py` from a Python 3.6 script.

I am working on Windows 7

This is the 2.7 script:

```
#! C:\Python27\python.exe

import sys

sys.stdout.write("Hello from version %s\n" % (sys.version,))
```

If I launch it from the cmd window, it will return that it is using the 2.7 version,
but if I call it from the 3.6 script with this instruction:

`exec(open("pp.py").read())`

then it will answer that it is using Python 3.6

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Python exec executes a string of code in the current version.
I think you'll have to run a new process using the python version you want.
If you need to read return values, use the Pipes, as described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes)

Follow the step [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34838251/1804272), and you'll have a distinction between python 2 and 3 (or use aliases in linux).

Then, you can use the [Process](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class) class to to run your script.