# How to run a python program in a shell without typing "python"

Tags: python

I am new to python. I wrote a program which can be executed by typing `python Filecount.py ${argument}` Why I see my teacher can run a program by only typing `Filecount.py ${argument}`. How to achieve that?

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: If Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1934675/1726343

Comment: It's worth noting that if your instructor is really using `Filecount.py` as opposed to `./Filecount.py` that he has likely also [added its directory to his PYTHONPATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make it executable

```
chmod +x Filecount.py
```

and add a [hashbang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) to the top of `Filecount.py` which [lets the os know](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) that you want to use the [python interpreter](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interpreter.html#executable-python-scripts) to execute the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then run it like

```
./Filecount.py args
```

Comment: `/usr/bin/env` is preferred to `/bin/python`. There is not even a proper `/bin` directory on my system (this would resolve through a symlink). Also, on certain Arch-based distros, this would resolve to Python 3, not Python 2, whereas I believe the `/usr/bin/env` style resolves as expected.

Answer (score 2):

in linux-based OSs you must include a line (at the beginning of your script, i.e., the first line) like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

this tells the OS to seek your python interpreter at that location. this applies to any script.

remember to have the permissions in your script file (i.e. executable) for that to work.

Comment: As I pointed out on Andre's answer, the preferred shebang line is `/usr/bin/env python` or equivalent, rather than specifying the path where you suppose Python exists on the system.

Answer (score 2):

Add a shebang line to the top of your file: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Purpose

It will tell the system which executable to use in running your program.

For example, add

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

as the first line, and then change the permissions of the file so you can execute it.

```
chmod +x Filecount.py
```

Best of luck!