# Python command line tool can't understand subcommands

Tags: python, django

Python command line tool can't understand subcommands on my enviroment.

For example, I run this command, but prompt print Usage.
It doesn't understand subcommands.

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

Please advise me.

My environment is 2.7.6 on windows

Comment: can you post the "usage" command that is printed ?

Comment: Is python in your PATH environment variable? What about python\scripts? `(C:\Python27;C:\Python27\scripts)` Is Django installed?

Comment: I can run "import django".PATH have C:\Python27;C:\Python27\scripts.

Comment: "django-admin.py startproject mysite" result Usage.

Comment: try: `python django-admin.py startproject mysite`

Comment: @RobertoSánchez It results can't open file 'django-admin.py'

Comment: Try `python c:\path_to_django_installation\django-admin.py startproject mysite`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
python c:\path_to_django_installation\django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

In windows, by default, the O.S. doesn't know how to execute python scripts.

To get Windows runs automatically your Python scripts take a look to this post: [How to execute Python scripts in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934675/how-to-execute-python-scripts-in-windows)

Comment: Do you know how to run only "django-admin.py startproject mysite"?

Comment: See my updated answer. You need to configure default behavior for files with .py extension