# Installing Splunk SDK for Python

Tags: python, command-line, splunk

I'm trying to install the splunk SDK for Python. I run the following command, `"C:\Python\python.exe" "C:\Python27\splunk-sdk-python-1.5.0\setup.py"`, and I get the following results: [image: Error Results from Command].

I've tried putting the `splunklib` folder in multiple stpots within the `Python27` directory. None of the location seem to work. I also tried changing the registry values: [How to execute Python scripts in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934675/how-to-execute-python-scripts-in-windows).

Any help as to how to install the Splunk SDK for Python would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try installing it with pip instead? `pip install splunk-sdk`

Comment: No, when I type in `pip install splunk-sdk`, my command prompt says, `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows, let me know if that helps (remember the SDK doesn't work with Python 3.x)

Comment: Got it working thanks to your link!

Answer (score 0):

In case you have not resolved pip, the below command should work to install modules with pip.  I have multiple versions of Python and this is how I install to the correct location.

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install splunk-sdk
```

Answer (score -2):

First install pip in windows, then using pip:

pip install splunk-sdk

Regards