# How to write an interactive shell in Python?

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x

Is it **possible** to run python script as if it's a command line interpreter, Example :

```
from sys import argv

argv=argv[1:]
str=''.join(argv)
import os
def ls():
    x=os.listdir(os.getcwd())
    for file in x:
        print(file)
if str =='ls':
    ls()
```

in this case I used argv to pass arguments, but can I want the code to behave like a command line interpreter and call my functions example:

myscript> ls
file.py
myscript>

**Note** :Sorry if i didn't explain my idea clearly, English is not my native language.

**Update** : some people said my question is duplicated and the same question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934675/how-to-execute-python-scripts-in-windows) but i repeat , I want to make "interactive shell" not "How to execute Python scripts in Windows"

Comment: If you run the Python interpreter, you can import a file and run is that way. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: No, what i want is to run the script as an external program , the script calls the functions you created in the script but without "()" of the function, the best word to describe what i want  is "interactive shell"

Comment: not really, here i am trying to make interactive shell not "how to pass arguments correctly"
guys let me explain more, when you open cmd you type ls/dir (depending on the os) to run the command , and then the cmd continues to execute the next command the user enter that's what i mean't.

Answer (score 2):

After a long search i found a module named **cmdln** which provides the best functions to do such tasks , Example :

```
import cmd

class HelloWorld(cmd.Cmd):
    """Simple command processor example."""

    def do_greet(self, line):
        print ('hello')

    def do_EOF(self, line):
           #this command will make you exit from the shell
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HelloWorld().cmdloop()
```

When you run the script , It will be like:

```
(Cmd) greet
hello
(Cmd) print
string
(cmd) EOF
```

Then the shell will stop , Thanks for  everyone who tried to help me.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, You want a [`REPL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) which can functions like your own version of `ls` using python. This answer is based on above assumption.

People have done that actually, for instance [`xonsh`](http://www.xonsh.org) using [`python-prompt-toolkit`](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit). Would like to suggest you to use a framework to reduce development time. 
If you want to do from scratch, Idea is to use loop waiting for command, execute the function, print and then wait

Answer (score -2):

Yes, check about [hashbang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

Basically, you just have to add this as first line in your file

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

also change file mode to executable

`chmod +x yourfile.py`

And you'll able to execute the file as a regular command. The point is that under the hood it just calls appropriated interpreted for your file (and using hashbang you just specify needed interpreter).

Comment: Sadly i am using windows, not linux.

Comment: In that case it's duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934675/how-to-execute-python-scripts-in-windows

Comment: not really, here i am trying to make interactive shell not "how to pass arguments correctly"

Comment: Doesn't actually address the user's question.  He's trying to make an interactive shell.