# AWS Python - Windows - Running a script after I create an instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, paramiko

I have made much progress.

My imports are:

```
import boto.rds as rds
import boto3 as b3
import boto.ec2 as ec2
from boto.manage.cmdshell import sshclient_from_instance
```

I can connect to my aws using:

```
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-west2',aws_access_key_id='MY_ID', aws_secret_access_key='MY_PASS')
```

I can create an instance using:

```
conn_args = {
    'aws_access_key_id': 'MY_KEY',
    'aws_secret_access_key': 'MY_PASS',
    'region_name': 'us-west-2'
}

ec2_res = b3.resource('ec2', **conn_args)

new_instance = ec2_res.create_instances(
    ImageId='ami-123456',
    MinCount=1,
    MaxCount=1,
    InstanceType='t2.micro',
    KeyName='my-keyname',
SecurityGroups=[
        'my-securitygroup'
    ]
    )
```

Now, when I try to run a command on my new instance I am banging my head against a wall.

I am trying something like:

```
ssh_client = sshclient_from_instance(instance,
                                     'C:\\users\\%USER%\\aws\\windows-west-keypair.pem',
                                     user_name='Administrator')

status, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.run('cd')
```

But I get back:

```
C:\Users\%USER%\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\paramiko\hostkeys.pyc in load(self, filename)
     93         :raises IOError: if there was an error reading the file
     94         """
---> 95         with open(filename, 'r') as f:
     96             for lineno, line in enumerate(f, 1):
     97                 line = line.strip()

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\%USER%/.ssh/known_hosts'
```

Connecting via ssh to my aws instance is a new thing for me, so I do not expect there to be a directory/file.

What do I require to be there? Is there anything I need to install in advance? What exactly is going wrong?

I feel so close, yet so far!

Any help would be great.

Comment: Is it a Windows Instance?

Comment: @error2007s Yes it is a windows instance.

Comment: You cannot Ssh into a Windows instance using a pem file check this steps to connect to AWS Windows EC2 instance http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinginstances-rdp.html

Comment: @error2007s Sorry it wasn't clear from the question but I want to run the script on the ec2 instance programatically. Meaning - after I create the instance I want to say `instance.run_command('python my_python_script.py')` - meaning - how do I access to command line programatically?

Comment: I guess there is a error the way you are running script in widows check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934675/how-to-execute-python-scripts-in-windows

Comment: @error2007s but you are totally missing the question. how do I access the command line via boto/boto3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you cannot directly ssh into windows.

so to come back on your initial requirement : *Running a script after I create an instance* I would not do that from your python script but instead have script on the ec2 instance and have them automatically running on ec2 instance startup

You can have [user data script](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-add-user-data) that will run on your instance. on windows instance, you can run basic cmd script or powershell script

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For someone facing this use case they should go with a linux instance, not windows.

Comment: sure its even better !

Comment: Frederic, do you use phantomjs on linux instance?

Comment: I run phantomjs on linux box (ubuntu) not running on AWS though, they were running on VM

Comment: Do you have any comment on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066060/running-phantomjs-on-linux-using-python

Comment: I'll look tomorrow when I can access my VM running ubuntu but it sounds like 32 vs 64 bits issue

Comment: Hi it was exactly what you said (32 v 64 bit).