# Python: Can't Find Module When Running Script Within a Script

Tags: python, import, subprocess

I created a Python program A for which I later wrote another Python program B that called A using the subprocess library. I had a module foo installed in A which worked perfectly fine until I started calling the program from B. Now, I get the error:

```
ImportError: no module named foo
```

when B is called. I am sure that the module is installed correctly, because when I enter a python shell from the same directory as A and B, I am able to import foo and use its functions successfully. So, why wouldn't foo import correctly in this situation?

**EDIT**

I call program B from program A using the following call.

```
call(["python", "levMap9.py", inputFilePath, outputFilePath, scalingFactor])
```

In program B (levMap9.py), I make the following import, which gives the import error for some reason

```
import Levenshtein as LV
```

**EDIT2**

I realize that it is probably worth mentioning that these programs worked fine when I initially developed them on OSX, but now are having this problem on a Windows 8 machine.

Comment: Could you eventually provide some minimal working three python file code, so one can directly spot the culprit (it soon starts to bend my old brain, when I have to follow such a setting in prose ;-) Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Just a moment.

Comment: And when one outputs `levMap9.py` perspective on `sys.path` in that call situation (via print or raise or in an `except ImportError ...` clause of a try block around the `Levenshtein` import effort ... would it contain the folder needed? Are the "places" of the two files relevant (compared to the place ot the imported modules implementation)?

Comment: Both A and B have the same absolute file path.

Comment: ... then they would be identical ;-) but got it: Same folder. Ok. Sometimes it is better to show a more wide area of your problem to get answers: So albeit these scripts are both coded in python, you have to call them "like alien binaries" and A calling B worked, but B calling A does not? The working case, could it be shown in the question? I ask myself in these situations of refactoring: What did I change, to make it break? But then I look at my screen or git move backward and forward in time ... so please try to check that.

Comment: I think I've got the problem figured out, but thank you for your help.

Comment: You may want to construct and show us a [mcve].

Comment: Well, this question is resolved. But I will keep that in mind for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding the path to the Levenshtein module in PYTHONPATH (it already existed in PATH), and that solved my problem; though I don't entirely understand why. Thanks to those who contributed advice.

**EDIT**

Found the real answer to my problem here:  [How to execute Python scripts in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934675/how-to-execute-python-scripts-in-windows)