# Unable to Launch RIDE from command prompt

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

I want to start using the RIDE tool for automation but I am currently unable to launch it from the command prompt. The following are what I have installed.

1. Python 2.7.11 (32bit)
2. Wx Python 2.8.12.1(unicode) for Python 2.7
3. robotframework 3.0.2 (pip installed)
4. robotframework-ride 1.5.2.1 (pip installed)

When I launch ride.py from cmd, it opens up a word file which has the same `ride.py` which is installed in the `C:\Python27\Scripts` folder.

The same setup works on a different machine. I don't understand why in this machine, it opens up a word document instead of launching RIDE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute Python scripts in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934675/how-to-execute-python-scripts-in-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a right click on ride.py and choose python as default program.

Answer (score 0):

in my machine python 2.7.15 is auto updated from 2.7.14. When to try to launch Ride.py it throws an error 
wxPython not found.
You need to install wxPython 2.8.12.1 or 3.0.2 or newer with unicode support to run RIDE. wxPython can be downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/

Although is wxpython 2.8.12.1 installed its doesn't recognize it. can anyone help out how can i over come this issue. 
I have Ride 2.0a1. should I downgrade ride or how can i fix this issue.