# Python file wont open without using the python exe on the cmd

Tags: python, windows, cmd, path

I'm trying to launch python file (here pdfid.py) from my cmd like that :
`pdfid.py mypdf.pdf`

But the .py file don't work

But it worked when I use the cmd :

`python <PATH>\pdfid.py mypdf.pdf`

I already added the pdfid on my windows PATH and python (python version 3)

I tried to change the executable python who launched the pdfid.py but it didn't worked
I tried to create a shortcut pdfid.py who launched the cmd : `cmd /k <PATH>/pdfid.py` but it don't work either

Comment: [Setting "open with"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1934695/10513287) might be enough, but the other answer has a detailed manual explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ivvija [Setting "open with"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1934695/10513287) did help me

When I ftype my Python.File, it was linked to `C:\Python27\python.exe` and not to `C:\Windows\py.exe`

I changed it with the command line :

```
ftype Python.File="C:\Windows\py.exe" "%1" %*
```

> `%1` to pass script name and all command-line parameters `%*` to py executable

But it was not enough, I had also to change the properties of the file .py to open it with py.exe